# Given that $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx +d$ what can be deduced about a,b,c and d?

Tags: functions

Given that $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx +d$ what can be deduced about a,b,c and d in the following cases

a)$f(x)$ is an even function

b)$f(x)$ is an odd function

c)$f(x) = |f(x)|$ for all values of x

d)$f(x) = -|f(x)|$ for all values of x

For a) I have said, if f(x) is even, then

$-ax^3 + bx^2 -cx + d = ax^3 + bx^2 +cx + d$

$\implies ax^2 + c = 0 \implies a=c=0$

For b) I have said, if f(x) is odd, then

$-ax^3 + bx^2 -cx + d = -ax^3 - bx^2 - cx - d$

$\implies bx^2 + d = 0 \implies b=d=0$

These are correct as given in my text book. But I do not know how to proceed with c) and d)

Part c) seems to say the function is always positive and d) seems to say it is always negative. I wonder if I am right to think that and if so how I can solve the questions.

Comment: For the next two, think about the range of a cubic function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: In c) and d) $f$ is always non-negative or always non-positive. If $a>0$ then $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ and $f(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to -\infty$. Hence, c) and d) cannot hold in this case. Similarly, c) and d) cannot hold if $a<0$. Thus, $a=0$ in the cases c) and d). Now we are reduced  to quadratic function $f$. I will let you handle the rest.

[Final answer for c): $a=b=c=0, d\geq 0$ or $a=0, b>0$ and $c^{2} \leq 4bd$].